# How to select two relational tables in Laravel that select all fields from the first and one field in the second step

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-8, balde

I wish you are doing well. This is my controller code and what I want to do. From the defined table of the projects in the database, I will display the values ​​of the 'title',  and 'description'. and from the defined table of images, I will show only the first uploaded photo. How can I fetch values ​​from these tables and send them to the blade and display them in it?

```
class ProjectsController extends Controller
{
 public function gallery()
 {
  $projects =  \App\Models\Project::orderBy('id', 'desc')
  ->join('images', 'projects.id', '=', 'images.project_id')
  ->select('projects.*','images.url')->get();
  
  return view('projects',compact('projects'));
 }}
```

[Design plan I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTLkR.png)

But the external result is that it shows a photo steadily.

[The result with a still image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZctUt.png)

This is blade code

```
<div class="container d-flex flex-column flex-md-row flex-wrap justify-content-around py-2 px-auto mx-auto">
@foreach($project as $data)<div class="containe position-relative col-11 col-md-3 mx-auto mx-sm-1 my-2">
<a href="{{route('projects.show', $data->id)}}">
    <img src="{{ #problem I had# }}" class="d-block w-100 h-auto rounded-4" alt="">
<div class="overlay position-absolute top-0 h-100 w-100 text-white d-flex flex-column text-center justify-content-center rounded-4">
  <h4 class="fw-bold">{{Str::limit($data->title, 20)}}</h4>
  <p>{{Str::limit($data->description, 100)}}</p>
</div>
</a></div>@endforeach
```

This is the Image Model

```
class Image extends Model{
use HasFactory;

protected $table = 'images';

protected $fillable = [
        
    'url', 'project_id'
];

public function project()
{
return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Project', 'project_id');
}}
```

This is the Project Model

```
class Project extends Model{
use HasFactory;
use SoftDeletes;
use Activable;

protected $table = 'projects';

protected $fillable = [

    'title',
    'description',
    'content',
    'is_active',
    'status', 
];

protected $casts = [
    'is_active' => 'boolean',
    'created_at' => 'datetime',
];

protected $guarded = [];

public $timestamps = true;

public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Image', 'project_id');
}

}
```

This is the dd test
[dd($project)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XmU0.png)

The last dd test
[->with('images') dd test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6A0Yt.png)

Comment: Is the `title` and `description` fields in your `projects` table?

Comment: yes, projects table have fields ´title´ and ´description´ and imags table field is ´url´

Comment: Did you try using Developer tools, like google chrome inspect element? Maybe it does have title and description, Maybe you're just having a CSS problem

Comment: No, there is no CSS problem. The problem is with the controller and blade. The images table has a field name  project_id that relates to the field of id in the projects table. For example, there are several 'url' fields whose 'project_id' is '1' and 'projects' has a field of 'id'  is '1'. I want to have one field of url, not all

Comment: Did you try to debug it? Try putting `dd($projects)` in your controller to see if it has the desired values?

Comment: This is the dd that you can see it returns more than one field of 'url'. for example, in a post that contains 4 images or 'url', the post is repeated 4 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using joins, use relationships instead. Eager load the images, using `with()`, for optimal query execution.

```
$projects =  Project::orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->with('images')
    ->get();
```

Since it is a one to many relationship, you either have to take the first image or loop all the images.

Take the first image.

```
<img src="{{ $project->images->first()->url }}" class="d-block w-100 h-auto rounded-4" alt="">
```

Iterate through it.

```
@foreach($project->images as $image)
    <img src="{{ $image->url }}" class="d-block w-100 h-auto rounded-4" alt="">
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks,
This is an error message.

Class "App\Model\Image" not found

This error is part of the 'Project' model -> return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Image', 'project_id');

Comment: Something is wrong with your image class, check that the file is located the correct place compared to the namespace and the file is named the same as the class with .php added. Instead of doing class reference as a string doing use App\Models\Image; $this->hasMany(Image::class); is also an option.

Comment: 1. I changed the above command like this. <img src="{{ $data->images->first()->url }}" class="d-block w-100 h-auto rounded-4" alt="">

Comment: 3. I got in blade dd returns the image, but it still has an error.

Attempt to read property "url" on null

Comment: with that error there is no images on your project.

Comment: You were right, the problem was with the database. Many Many thanks